# Copy directory structure from Solaris preserving all the permissions and links

Tags: unix, solaris, tar

I am looking to copy a directory structure with Files, I am not looking for content a 0 byte file will do. 
I just need to copy the directory tree with 0 byte files and links preserving the properties of the file like- Permission, Owner, Group, ACL.

How do I copy / create a tar ball/ rsync  with Directories and 0 byte files with same ACL's, permissions, User, group and others.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that on Solaris with `rcp`, although it does give you full file contents. You can truncate the files afterward.

```
rcp -p foo bar
```

If you explicitly *don't* want the file contents, then this might not be the best option.